# Ssh console prints ^H when pressing the return key

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I did not know if I had to post that in a more system specific stack exchange. So please inform me where to go if this question does not belong here.

I am using mobaXterm tu SSH into a server. It worked fine for the last week, but since today, I have a behavior modification.

When I press the return key, it prints `^H` instead of deleting previous character.

For example:

```
# cd bni/^H^H^H
```

Why did it suddenly change and how can I configure it to actualy delete the character instead of printing this ?

Edit: With a new terminal, the "problem" does not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MobaXterm's changelog https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html, you can see they added a New option for sending ^H when pressing the backspace key in Version 3.0. It has a checkbox setting 'Backspace sends ^H' in Settings --> Terminal tab. 
You can also use Shift+Backspace to remove a character.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the stty command to set your erase character:

```
stty erase {press backspace to get the ^H character}
```

You may need to include this in your login scripts to make it permanent.